# How does the strong interaction “create” the nuclear force?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, pions

I’ve recently read that the strong interaction, that holds the quarks together to form protons and neutrons, also creates a residual force called the nuclear force, which holds the neutrons and protons together. **Why and how is the nuclear force a consequence of the strong interaction?**

Comment: The answer is the Yukawa meson theory of nuclear force. It involves the exchange of pions between the nucleons, which binds them together.

Comment: A residual force is a more general concept. For example, the force that binds electrically neutral atoms together to form molecules is also a residual force. There's no big mystery about it. The force is zero to first order, but it exists in higher orders of approximation.

Comment: Possible duplicates/worth checking: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685687/226902  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471075/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/513047/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693669/226902

Answer (score 0):

The nuclear force arises from the strong interaction and virtual gluon exchanges and color fluctuations within the quarks of the nuclei creat pions that are exchanged between nucleons

Comment: The beginning of your statement is essentially the definition of the strong force. Could you go more in depth about the creation and exchange of pions?